# AXIOS Async/Await How to best write the code?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, mobx-state-tree

I am writing my first ajax call using Axios, Mobx/Mobx State Tree (MST) and Reactjs.

In MST they have something called flows what basically does the same thing as async/await

```
 getCustomers: flow(function * (){
       const response = yield getEnv(self).axiosInstance.get("/Customers/Get");

       if(response.status === 200){
           // response.data
        } else {
             // error though not sure what the call is? response.error?
        }
}),
```

Is it as simple as this? Is that how I should be checking if the status is and error or if the status was ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mobx flow, future promise is handled the same as it is with `async/await` syntax, a successful resolve will be return as the result while a failed one will result in an error being thrown, waiting to be caught by a catch statement. You should use `try / catch` to catch the error. More on this topic can be found here: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/master/docs/concepts/async-actions.md

With the sample code you post, it also depends on how your endpoint handle error and the status code it returns. Basically, `axios` treat a 200 response as success, and other (400, 500) as failure. If your API follow this convention, you don't need to check `response.status` to see if the response is successful, but rely on `axios` to do it for you, an example can see below:

```
getCustomers: flow(function * (){
       try {
          const response = yield getEnv(self).axiosInstance.get("/Customers/Get");
          // Do something here if 200 response returned
       } catch (err) {
          // Error handling here when 500 returned
       }
})
```